# How to convert an DWORD value to an void* one?

Tags: c++, casting, visual-c++-2013

Given these `typedef`s and the value below:

```
typedef void  GTVOID;
typedef GTVOID *PARAM_VALUE;
typedef unsigned long UDGT32 
typedef UDGT32 PARAM_CONST;
typedef signed long DGT32;
typedef DGT32 RESULT_FUNC;

DWORD value = 1; // given from a define
```

How I can convert it to satisfy the needs of that device SDK function in C++?

```
RESULT_FUN RSetParam( PARAM_CONST DeviceParameter, PARAM_VALUE value);
```

The C reference code in samples is:

```
RSetParam( R_SOME_PARAM_CONST, (PARAM_VALUE)value );
```

I tried it below, but it's just weird. It compiles ok, works all day long and by some
creepy luck, starts throwing access violations out of blue:

```
RSetParam(R_SOME_PARAM_CONST, reinterpret_cast<void*> (value));
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I would use `reinterpret_cast<PARAM_VALUE>` ...

Comment: Read the documentation for that SDK function.

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to reinterpret the value `1` as an address. Depending on what the function `RSetParam` is doing with this address (value), the program may seg-fault. Especially, if it tries to write to this address.

I think, the function `RSetParam` awaits an address to a variable as second argument. The type of the variable might depend on something else, that is, why the adress must be passed as `void *`.

So, if you want to pass number 1 as DWORD you have to allocate a variable on the stack first and then pass its address:

```
DWORD tmp = 1; // given from define
RSetParam( R_SOME_PARAM_CONST, (PARAM_VALUE) &tmp ); // note the '&' !
```

Comment: Some (poorly designed) APIs expect `long` and `void *` to be used interchangeably; the function implementation will cast back to `long` if the value of the first argument indicates this is supposed to be a numeric value.  OP's "reference code" suggests that perhaps this is such an API.